# List With Scroll Arrow Left-Right in HTML, CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, scroll

I have this list with scroll arrow in left side and right side. But I don't have any ideas. What should i can do now?

[image: http://i1121.photobucket.com/albums/l502/pmtan/Parents.jpg]

Comment: we also have no idea what you want to do...

Comment: Sorry about not clearly described. I want to create a list like this. I like a list  in a scroll bar with no bar. When you click left or right arrow button, a list will scroll left or right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cycle2 jQuery plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: Can you explain to me? Why use this plugin? I see this is a plugin for slide show. Thanks

Comment: If you want to use to the arrows to cycle from one entry to the other, Cycle2 has a carousel plugin that might help. Besides that, Cycle2 itself has a large set or callback functions and options which will help you achieve what you want.

If you do not want to use the plugin, you can simple create an JS array with the entries you want and bind functions to your arrows to increase and decrease the index and change the appropriate classes etc...